# What exactly is "anonymous" in the call stack from Chrome devtools?

Tags: devtools

Whenever I'm debugging in chrome, I mostly see **anonymous** included in the call stack, what exactly is that anonymous?

Answer (score 2):

These are anonymous functions like:

```
() => { ... }
```

Methods without name.

Comment: Okay I get you now; so it means the debugger paused in a method that is "anonymous" right?

Comment: The debuggers paused at any method. No matter anonymous or not.